# Elasticsearch - group by element in child collection

Tags: elasticsearch, group-by, database, nosql

I have documents of following format in an elastic search index:

```
{
  "item":"Firefox",
  "tags":["a","b","c"]
},
{
  "item":"Chrome",
  "tags":["b","c","d"]
}
```

I want to group by each element in the tags property, so that I get results like:

```
"a" = 1, "b" = 2, "c" = 2, "d" = 1
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you index (write) your document to, 
index= x, type =y then ,

```
POST x/y/_search
{
    "size":0,
    "aggs":{
        "t":{
            "terms" :{
                "field" :"tags"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To know its working, just learn elasticsearch.